# Jquery Validation rule for entire form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In Jquery Validation plugin we use rules on element. 
Is there a way we can attach a rule for the **form** not to a particular element?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to accomplish by attaching a rule to the form?

Comment: @user1618143 I want to check two elements and see if they have a specific value. I can attach the rule to one of the element that checks the validation logic. But I was wondering I can do it any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the answer is that it does not work like that.  Rules are evaluated for each input element because that's where the data is entered.

Otherwise, your OP is unclear about the reason you'd need to do such a thing.

As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534531/jquery-validation-rule-for-entire-form/27535708#comment43498242_27534531):

> *"I want to check two elements and see if they have a specific value. I can attach the rule to one of the element that checks the validation logic. But I was wondering I can do it any other way."*

- You could create a custom rule using [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) using your own validation function that compares the two fields to the value, to each other, or whatever you want.
- You would declare this new rule on one or more fields the same as you would declare any other standard rule or method.
- As needed, you could optionally use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) to *combine* similar repeating error messages into one.

Answer (score 3):

I kind of found a bit of a hack-ish way to have a full form validator.  Hopefully, this will be helpful to those who simply want to run a method that returns true or false to determine validity if you have a weird quirk in your form.

In my form I added two elements:
First, where I want the error to be announced.

```
<div id="customErrorPlacement"></div>
```

Second, I added a new hidden input element

```
<input class="hidden" type="text" name="bevalid"></input>
```

In my js file

I had my form valid function

```
var myCustomValidFunc = function() {
   //test form here:  return true or false;
}
```

I added the custom function to the rules set before calling form.validate()

```
$.validator.addMethod('myCustomValidFunc', myCustomValidFunc, $.validator.format("This form isn't right; here's how to fix it"));
```

Then in my form.validate options:

```
  rules: {
         .....
        'bevalid': {
            "myCustomValidFunc": true
        }
    },
    ignore:[],
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == 'bevalid') {
             error.insertBefore($("#customErrorPlacement"));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  you need to add "ignore: []," to the form validate function to clear the function default values, as new versions of jquery automatically ignore hidden input values.

Comment: A few years later & I had a case of a form with an associated, but independent form that was related to associations to the primary record you could add or remove from the same page. Wanted to validate the main form along with saying "one or more associations". The outline of the approach above was a good solution, thanks.